# How to call a method from current Activity by clicking a notification

Tags: android, kotlin

My application handles notification in 2 ways
1/ If the app is in background, inactive, or killed, clicking the notification will open it from the beginning.
2/ If the app is currently on foreground, clicking the notification will call a certain method of the current top activity.

My question: How could I call a method of the current top activity by clicking the notification?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you know about different launch modes of activity and hoping you already have launch mode of that activity set to singleTask so that if your task is running your activity is not recreated and a callback onNewIntent() is called .You should call your method from here.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
 //Call your method here
}
```